# Index ordering when using math symbols

Tags: indexing, sorting

I'm making an index where certain entries start with the math symbols `$k$`, `$\mathcal{C}$`, `$\ast$-a...`. In the first two cases, I want them to appear in the index as if they start with k and c respectively. In the last case I want the index to ignore `$\ast$-` and treat the word as if it begins with the letter `a`.

How might I go about doing that?

Comment: `\index{k@$k$}` and `\index{c@$\mathcal{C}$}`

Comment: @egreg: why don't you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to give these entries a sort field.  you've actually chosen the easiest approach, sorting them in with the alphabetic entries.  egreg has provided good examples for the first two:

`\index{k@$k$}` and `\index{c@$\mathcal{C}$}`

my suggestion for the `*` is

`\index{a sterisk@$\ast$}`

including a space after the `a` to make sure it sorts at the beginning.

i've been compiling a set of notes on how to prepare a "clean" index, presenting tactics for avoiding all the problems i've seen in my experience as author technical support for the ams; when it's ready for general consumption, it will be posted on the ams web site for general reference, and i'll update this answer with a link.

**Addendum:** 
(1) Regarding the index sort: Remember that the sorting is parallel at each level, so if a symbol is subsidiary to another entry, a sort field needs to be provided *at the relevant level*.  Say you have this two-level entry with multiple sub-entries at the second level:

> Entry
>    First sub-entry
>    Omega (the symbol)

Assuming you want the sub-entries in alphabetical order, you should enter the second sub-entry as

```
\index{Entry!Omega@$\Omega$}
```

otherwise it will be sorted before the first sub-entry.

The same principle applies at the third level, if your index entries are nested that deeply.

(2) Between the time of the original answer and this addendum, I have retired, and there is no longer any question that an answer might be the "official" position of my employer.  Hence any posting by me will now be in "proper" upper- and lowercase.

There is another consequence implied here.  The notes I was compiling on preparing a "clean" index weren't completed before I left AMS.  I do intend to complete them, but it's not certain that they will be posted on the AMS web site.  They *will*, however, be posted to CTAN and I'll give a link when this happens.

**Update:** 
Although the notes I was preparing were not extended to cover all topics I had planned before my retirement from AMS, the document (which does cover quite a broad range of situations) has been rescued from near oblivion and posted on the AMS website at https://www.ams.org/arc/tex/howto/index/0index-notes.pdf .  I do still intend to complete it, but believe what's there now should be helpful.

Comment: Makeindex knows a section for symbols before the letter A. Therefore I would start the sort key with a symbol, if the symbols should be sorted in the symbol section: `\index{$asterisk@$\ast$}`, `\index{$colon@:}`, &hellip;

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek -- yes, there is such a section, but it's up to the author to decide where s/he wants symbols to go.  authors sometimes decide to put symbols in a second, separate, index, rather than having them lumped together in a separate section at the top of the main index.  even so, the ordering depends entirely on how the index entries are input. (makeindex just does a raw ascii sort, which is not intuitive in the case of symbols.)  if you've ever been faced with two pages of apparently randomly ordered symbol entries, you'll appreciate the problem.

Comment: Were the notes ever published?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides -- sadly, it's still on my "to do" list, er, pushdown stack.  it'll come to the surface sometime, but right now, i can't predict when.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Will be looking forward to it :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Has the notes been finished and posted somewhere?

Comment: @MadHatter -- sigh.  not yet.  there's still one topic unfinished, about how one might compile an index-like section manually, but have the page numbers filled in automatically.  i should tidy up the parts that are done, and post that, marked :preliminary".  thanks for the noodge.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the update. I am looking forward to the notes :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I hate to nag but did you eventually get somewhere with these notes? :)

Comment: @EivindDahl -- still working; new developments in the glossaries area have caused me to rethink this area.  (please keep nagging.)

Comment: Very well, I'll put it on my schedule a couple years down the line haha

Comment: @EivindDahl -- quite by accident, i've come across another question that i answered, that contains a link to the index-notes-so-far on the ams ftp server: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297508 .  what's there might be useful, and when the information on indexing symbols is added, the new version of the document will replace the one that's there now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the heads-up! That's very nice, though I seem quite unable to access it!

Comment: @EivindDahl -- you're probably behind a firewall or using an unforgiving browser.  ftp servers are becoming unwelcome, seen as potentially insecure or hazardous.  ams is working on migrating everything to its web server, but progress is (sadly) glacial.

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're right! chrome did not like it one bit, but firefox had no problem

Comment: I'm having a problem that `\index{Farbmodell!$Y'CBCR@Y'C_BC_R'$|main}` is sorted before `\index{Farbmodell!CIE RGB|(}` and `\index{Farbmodell!CIE RGB|)}`; should I open a new question?

Comment: @U.Windl -- you *could* open a new question, but I may as well add this to my existing answer since the same principle applies, just at the "second level".

Comment: @barbara beeton: While writing the question, I realized that I had misplaced the first `$`, but the question turned out to describe another problem (`Y'` becoming plain `Y`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm no longer able to access your notes on indexing at ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/0index-notes.pdf, neither with Chrome nor with Firefox. Would it be possible to upload them elsewhere?

Comment: @fhenneke -- The ftp site was destroyed without saving anything, but the person who now handles the functions that were mine has done some archaeology, found a copy, and posted it in a "permanently trustworthy" locationi.  Kudos, gold stars, and many thanks for his efforts!  (I'll update the other question as well.  Thanks for the reminder.)