# Occasionally wrong page numbers for index entries

Tags: indexing

I have observed that sometimes entries appear in the index *not* listed with the page number of the page where they are actually displayed, but with the page number increased by one. Apparently that is an annoyance, as it forces me to recheck all my index. I've seen it in footnotes, and solved it by taking the index command out of the footnote. I've also seen it when the word appears in the last paragraph of the page, even if quite a few lines before the end, which I could solve also by setting the marker at the end of the previous paragraph.

Are there some common mistakes leading to the described behaviour which I should avoid, or have I found a bug and should try to find out what it is?

I've tried to make a MWE, but so far failed to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: The standard indexing commands are quite reliable. So imho your document is doing something wrong.

Comment: i'd be interested in seeing an example with the index term in the last paragraph of a page, where the `\index{...}` precedes the term to be indexed, as `\index{this term}this term`.  i've seen this happen when this is input as `this term\index{this term}` for a multi-word term, but not (yet) when the opposite order is used.  (i'm trying to write a "comprehensive" guide to reliable indexing.  avoiding the off-by-one problem is a major component.)

Comment: It probably won't help but have you tried all the usual: clearing all generated files, and recompiling, including an extra compile when you think you're done?

Comment: it's really difficult to make a MWE in this case and so it's very difficult to say but your second example is really strange.

Comment: @barbarabeeton good continuation

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just tried your suggestion to shift the indexing command from after the word (where I usually have them) to just before the word indexed, and that did solve it for that case, so so far I'm afraid I don't have the case you're interested in. I will try it out on other ones as well and let you know if I find one. Would you then generally recommend to keep the index command before the word indexed (assuming it repeats literally in the text)?

Comment: @muk.li -- my recommendation is to place `\index{...}` so that it gives the correct page number.  so if the term is a full name, e.g. `Albert Einstein`, a person looking in the index will look for "Einstein" -- then put `\index` *after* the name.  if they'd look for the first word of the phrase, e.g. "probability theory", put it before.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I had one case which you might find interesting: A last paragraph of the page, contained in a quote environment, in which there is a footnote containing an item to be indexed. I had the index command in the footnote, and it appeared in the index as 35 instead of 34. I took the index command out of the footnote, just before the footnote command, but that didn't fix it. It got fixed when I moved it to the end of the paragraph before. Possibly relevant to that is another footnote whose marker was at the beginning of the page, also containing the word, but no index command for it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The second of the footnotes on that page extended into the next page, possibly also relevant.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have now found another simpler example of what you were interested in: On the last paragraph of a page `\index{Atimārga}Atimārga` gets indexed as 50 instead of 49. I've tried to reproduce the behaviour by copying the paragraph into an empty document and push it down on the page so that it breaks over to the next page, but in that example the indexing worked correctly.

Answer (score 9):

based on the discussion in the comments, the following suggestion will not
solve all problems, but it should get rid of some of them.

if a term to be indexed falls near the end of a page, it is generally a good
idea to place the `\index` entry before the text string, especially if the
term contains more than one word, or might be hyphenated.

in the case of a multi-word term, consider what a person looking in the
index will be looking for on the referenced page.  if the term is a name,
e.g. `Albert Einstein`, a person looking in the index will look for "Einstein" -- then put `\index` after the name. if they'd look for the first word of the phrase, e.g. "probability theory", put it before.

i have compiled a document addressing various problems that arise
in indexing; it has been posted on [the ams web server](https://www.ams.org/arc/tex/howto/index/0index-notes.pdf).
(this document is still a work in progress, but is far enough along to
be useful.  the incomplete portions are marked as such.  comments are
welcome; the address is included in the introduction.)

the "off by one" problem is encountered quite frequently, and is
addressed in my "manual" in greater detail than described above.

Comment: Wow, extremely impressive!

Comment: @WillRobertson -- what, the answer, or the "how to" writeup?

Comment: The howto of course :) I should have been more clear. indexing is one of the less well documented areas of LaTeX I think, great to see such a comprehensive resource. Perhaps TUGboat would be interested in publishing it :)