# Index sorting with a mix of greek and roman letters and single letter index entries

Tags: indexing, sorting, makeindex, makeidx

## A mix of Roman, Greek, and single letter index entries

I am typing my thesis and have a mix of regular words, mathematics using greek symbols, and the occasional one letter word (such as the programming language C), and I noticed that my system for ensuring these are sorted correctly has fallen short.

## An example of the problem

Notice where the `$chi^2$` appears in the index:

[image]

whereas what I am after is

[image]

## My current system

1. If a regular roman word then just use index as intended such as `\index{Something}`, including for single letter words such as `\index{C}` or `\index{R}`.
2. If there is a roman letter which I want to come first but in math mode then I use a single underscore, such as `\index{p_value@{$p$-value}}` or `\index{t_distribution@{$t$-distribution}}`. The underscore ensures these appear first in their sort field.
3. If there is a leading greek mathematical letter then I want this to appear before the roman entries, so I use a double underscore such as `\index{d_delta_function@{$\delta$-function}}`.

Where possible I try and use a leading textual entry and so would use `Dirac-$\delta$ function` over `$\delta$-function`. However, I would use the greek symbols in preference to the greek letter spelt out, and so would use `$\beta$-radiation` rather than `beta-radiation`.

## One workaround

I notice that if I write `C\index{C@{C}}` rather than `C\index{C}` then the sorting appears to be better, but I haven't tested this fully and it smells like a bad practice. I have also in the past accidentally duplicated many index entries by having a trailing space such as `\index{Something }` which is a pain to debug, so am apprehensive about encouraging that I add one or two trailing spaces to every index.

***How can I get the desired sorting, and how should I revise my indexing system for future documents?***

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index{d_delta_function@{$ \delta $-function}|see {Dirac-$ \delta $ function}}

The C\index{C} 
%C\index{C@{C}} % <-- This gives better sorting. 
language is great, and C++\index{C++} is okay, as too is $ C $\#\index{C_sharp@{C\#}}, but if you want to compute a $ p $-value\index{p_value@{$ p $-value}} for a Gaussian random variable with inverse cumulative distribution function $ \Phi^{-1} $\index{p__phi_inverse@{$ \Phi^{-1} $}} then you may encounter difficulties with the probability density\index{Probability density} if it tends to a Dirac-$ \delta $\index{Dirac_delta_function@{Dirac-$ \delta $ function}} function. 

\clearpage 
This becomes worse if you want to handle a $ \chi^2 $-distribution\index{C@{$ \chi^2 $-distribution}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

## Related questions

[Index ordering when using math symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68240/106804)

Comment: Have a look at [this question and its answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522954/9632).

Comment: This seems appropriate for additional letters had I wanted a symbols column or an additional columns such as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272156/106804, but in this case I want them sorted under their corresponding Roman indices, and to appear first if it is in maths mode with priority given to greek letters.

Comment: Are you sure that xindex does not sort correctly "out of the box"?  If not, your option is probably to to build your sorting order using `\index{<expr>@<expr>}`. That is how LaTeX indexing works.

Comment: `xindex` doesn't seem to sort this correctly out of the box.

Comment: Well normally I would put things like `\chi` under symbols and not under a letter. But if you want to sort them there, and have normal 1-letter words, you will have to make their sort key longer so that you can put something before them in the sorting. So use for `C` e.g. `C1` then you have `C0..` for symbols.